# Bind List<Dictionary<string,string>> to DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("A","123");
dict.Add("B","456");
dict.Add("C","789");
dict.Add("D","000");
var list = new List<Dictionary<string,string>>(); //pretty much like a DataTable
list.Add(dict); //more than one dict in the list

//ddl is a dropdownlist
ddl.DataSource = list
ddl.DataTextField ="[A]";
ddl.DataValueField ="[C]";
ddl.DataBind();
```

For WPF, I can do similar binding above, but not in asp.net.

Comment: well you know that WPFs binding is a couple of magnitudes **better** than ASP.NETs? You will have to transform your data before binding them as DataSource - sorry.

Comment: You want to bind a string dictionary to dropdownlist in asp.net.Is it?

Answer (score 6):

You should bind your dictionary, not list. Something like this :

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
dict.Add("A","123");
...

ddl.DataSource = dict
ddl.DataTextField ="Key";
ddl.DataValueField ="Value";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4):

This works great for me:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myDict = Dictionary<string, string>();
myDict.Add("myKey","My test value");

@Html.DropDownList("SomeDropDown", new SelectList(myDict, "key", "Value"),
                   "--- Select tomething ---", new { @class = "myHtmlClassName" })
```